# Hide true modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, directory

The subject is package imports and the `__init__` file:
There is one quote in the specification that says

> these files serve to prevent directories with common names from
>   unintentionally hiding true modules that appear later on the module
>   search path. Without this safeguard, Python might pick a directory
>   that has nothing to do with your code, just because it appears nested
>   in an earlier directory on the search path.

Can you give me practical examples of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such quote in the current [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3).

[PEP 420 Implicit Namespace Packages (Python 3.3+) specifies](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/):

- If `<directory>/foo/__init__.py` is found, a regular package is imported and returned.
- If not, but `<directory>/foo.{py,pyc,so,pyd}` is found, a module is imported and returned. The exact list of extension varies by platform and whether the `-O` flag is specified. The list here is representative.
- If not, but `<directory>/foo` is found and is a directory, it is recorded and the scan continues with the next directory in the parent path.
- Otherwise the scan continues with the next directory in the parent path.

i.e., if `<directory>` is in `sys.path` then `import foo` might correspond to `<directory>/foo` even if there is no `<directory>/foo/__init__.py`. The pep is accepted therefore the risk of possible confusion due to an accidental `import foo` success is considered too minor compared to the benefit of having the namespace packages.

Unless you intend to provide a namespace package e.g., for plugin modules to be able to put them in different directories (installable as different OS packages) then you should always provide `__init__.py` for your Python package -- explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: I try the @Martijn example , and in fact the "images" directory was imported even if it does not have any __init__.py file,just because it was found earlier on the search path.I thought only directories containing the __init__.py file were imported.

Comment: @tt0686: yes, if there is no `images/__init__.py` or `images.{py,pyc,...}` in `sys.path` then `images` directory can cause `import images` to succeed: *"if `<directory>` is in `sys.path` then `import foo` might correspond to `<directory>/foo` even if there is no `<directory>/foo/__init__.py`"*

Comment: But what is the point of importing something without any statements or methods ? Just a directory ?

Comment: @tt0686: read [the rationale for pep 420](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#rationale) e.g., *"provide a namespace package e.g., for plugin modules to be able to put them in different directories (installable as different OS packages) "*

Comment: That means that in previous Python versions(before namespace packages) the directory without the __init__.py file will not be imported, correct ?

Comment: @tt0686: yes. You either get ImportError if the corresponding module (e.g., `foo.py`) is not found or ImportWarning otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow *any* directory to be seen as a package, then trying to import a module that exists both as a directory *and* as a module on the search path could pick the directory over the module.

Say you have a `images` directory *and* an `images.py` module. `import images` would find the `images` directory if it was found earlier on the search path.

By requiring a `__init__.py` to mark packages you make it possible to include such data directories next to your Python code without having to worry about masking genuine modules with the same name.